# Filtering with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-elb

I have a load-balancer running in AWS, which has a listener with a number of rules based on host header parameters.

Is it possible to use `--query` or `--filters` to filter out the `RuleArn` based on the host header?

So `aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:1234567890:listener/net/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890 --query 'Rules[].RuleArn' --output text` gives me all the RuleArns but I would like to add in an extra condition to only spit out the RuleArn based on the value of the host header I provide.

Comment: Take a look at the conditional examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html).

Comment: Thanks.. I've had a look at this. I'm just trying to figure out the right syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
❯❯ aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn \
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener/app/mytesting/86b9380a1a34/5ef713678269 \
--query 'Rules[?Actions[0].RedirectConfig.Host == `example.com`].RuleArn' \
--output text

arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567890:listener-rule/app/mytesting/86b9380a3a0c1a34/5ef7136ad78269/f04455bc36298f
```

Comment: Thanks @samtoddler